# Solving operations

Tags: java, string, algorithm, int

I am trying to write a program that will take an expression and solve it.  For example, if I were given 5 * 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 + 5 * 5 - 2, I should come to the answer of 41 using ArrayLists. To do this I have to convert an operation given into an int. Is there any way to convert a whole given string or int into an operation? I have tried using Integer.parseInt(givenString) but I get an error because of the "+", "-", "*", "/" signs.

Also, I have tried the following but I get the same error because of the signs

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int k=0;

    while (k!=-1)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please enter an operation to solve or enter -1 to stop");
    k= kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println(k);
    k=0;

    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("5 * 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 + 5 * 5 - 2"));`

Answer (score 0):

Just try with,

```
try {
            System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("5 * 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 + 5 * 5 - 2"));
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I think this defeats the purpose of the OP's assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to give you a starting point without writing code, because I want to avoid doing your homework for you.

You will want to go through your input string one character at a time, and decide whether each character is a number (or part of a number) or an operation (`+-*/`).  The list you should aim to form for your problem should look something like this:

`["5", "*", "5", "+", "2", "/", "2", "-", "8", "+", "5", "*", "5", "-", "2"]`

From there, manipulate the list as you need to solve the problem.